# Is there a way I can change the image uploaded to an answer upon mouseover?

Tags: support, images

I am looking for a way, in which an image uploaded and shown on a post, should change into a different post upon mouse-overing the image.

Let me give an example:

I have this image:[image]

I move my mouse over an image, it should change and show a different one instead, like this:

[image]

Is this possible? If so, how.

My apologies if I wasn't clear in what I am trying to say.

Comment: Do you mean when viewing a question or answer in this site, or something else?

Comment: If you're posting on Stack Overflow or here you can put the image in a stack snippet and then use CSS or javascript to manipulate it on hover. Of course that requires that the snippet be run but you can always state that in your question. Why not simply have two images and some text which says before and after though?

Comment: I have made an edit.

Comment: @SagarV for formatting an answer. Why do you require this?

Comment: I didn't see any purpose of this. I mean if this feature is implemented, it should be very easy to spam. That is a person upload a screenshot and when people mouseover the image, it show a spam image.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for your reply, but I have a hard time understanding what "stack snippet" and "javascript" are supposed to mean ( I am not computer-software oriented), so do you know anywhere I can learn what stack snippets mean?

Comment: That is not a tin can, so no, you can't do this.

Comment: @Won't Oh come on, what's it called then (fyi I am not editing the picture again)?

Comment: Ah I wanted a little mousie to pop out.